# Are linked files supported in an ASP.NET 1.1 project?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, csproj

Is there a way to have linked files in an ASP.NET 1.1 project?

What I did was to copy the linked file declaration from a DLL csproj to the file I want. But everytime I change the Web.csproj to add a new file, the links are deleted.

Is there a possible workaround? maybe inserting this in the build scripts or something like that?

Is this possible in .NET 2.0?

Comment: What is a link file? How do you use link files? Do you mean LINQ?

Comment: No, i mean those csharp files that are not inside the project folder and you want to compile them in but do not include them physically. These are useful when you have for example a GlobalAssemblyVersion that should be used in all your projects, but located in a single place.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I tagged your question with the visual-studio tag. What version of Visual Studio are you using? It's not supported in 2002 or 2003 according to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2009/04/02/linked-files-in-visual-studio-solutions.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2003 then linked files are not supported:

> If you want to explicitly add an item as a link, you can create links
>   in the following projects:
>
> - The solution, Visual C++, and other similar projects support only links, so all of the items in these projects are links. The project
>     does not attach a link indicator (a small arrow) to the item icon in
>     Solution Explorer.
> - Visual Basic, Visual C#, and other similar projects can accommodate both linked and physical project items. Linked items in these projects
>     display a link indicator attached to the icons of linked project
>     items.
>
> **Visual Basic Web, Visual C# Web and other similar projects, do not
>   support links to items**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92(v=VS.71).aspx

You can work around this by creating a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) (symlink) to the first instance of the file. The [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) makes it easy to do so in Windows Explorer and it will even add an arrow badge to the file's icon (you have to use NTFS). Or use the command line program [mklink](http://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cc753194%28WS.10%29.aspx):

```
> cd Project\Properties
> mklink AssemblyInfo.cs ..\..\Global\AssemblyInfo.cs
```

When you have created a symlink, it's as if the same file exists in both places. It's transparent to applications, including (I expect) Visual Studio 2003. This is **not** the same as a shortcut (.lnk file).

Comment: though I don't link symlink. I think is just too specific scenario and when by any means I delete both files, the symlink would be lost I presume

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: what I did in the end was to take another approach. I simply put a validation in my build script that if the csproj does not contain any reference to my AssemblyInfo files, the build failed.

This was ok because the only time they would be deleted, is when the csproj gets modified which is almost never.